# What is it? What am I?

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, geography

I've got the biggest nose but I might be lying.
 PS: This is my first attempt at riddles so be nice. Also, I've made this riddle myself so let's see how many "travelers" we have out there. :) 
 The "travelers" clue would have been enough for the keen eye but for those who think it's too broad, "It's a place to visit" (but I have to tell you that takes the fun out of it)

Comment: .....Pinocchio?

Comment: I'm not voting yet, but I expect this will be quickly tagged as 'too-broad', since there are many answers that could potentially fit these clues. In order to avoid that, I suggest you edit the question and add a line or two to narrow it down. :)

Comment: Possibly add more lines to the riddle? It's a little thin as is and might be marked too broad.

Comment: Ah interesting but that's not it. Besides, that would be I've got the biggest nose IF I might be lying. :)

Comment: Is there a "not" missing somewhere around the nose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you

> the Great Sphinx of Giza?
>  It is the largest monolithic statue in the world so it should have the largest nose, but it is also missing its nose, so it could be lying

Comment: The lying part might be that in mythology (Greek, I believe), the sphinx is known as a liar

Comment: @Moose, I couldn't find anything to support that. Do you know the specific myth?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is

> the Great Sphinx of Giza.

Also, this riddle was actually

> a clue from the first episode of the tv show 'Where on Earth is Carmen Sandiego?", episode titled "The Stolen Smile." The word "lying" in the clue was pronounced as "lyin'", a play on the word "lion" while also eluding to the fact that the nose is gone.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! In future, please check that the answer you're posting hasn't already been given - in this case, the same answer was given nearly three years ago. Good comment on the puzzle's origins, though.

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> a head on [Easter Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_Island)?

Comment: A+ for attempt but those heads do have nose. :)

Comment: Yes but some of them are lying.

Comment: But they are smaller in size than the sphinx (so not really the biggest nose)